# Add interactive chart to folium map

Tags: python, charts, interactive, folium, ipyleaflet

I want to add chart to folium map like below:

[enter image description here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/raw/master/widget_control.gif)

source: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet

But I cannot find any doc guiding to this. Can anyone help me with this?

I tried reading documentation in https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/index.html but there is no luck.
I expected to see some example code for adding chart to map (not adding chart to popup).

Answer (score -1):

**To add a chart to a map using Folium, you can follow these steps:**

> 1. Install the folium library by running pip install folium in your terminal or command prompt.

> 2. Import the necessary libraries in your Python script:

```py
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
```

> 3. Create a map object using the folium.Map() function:

```py
m = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=12)
```

Replace latitude and longitude with the coordinates of the center of your map.

> 4. Create a chart using your preferred charting library, such as matplotlib or seaborn. For example, let's create a simple bar chart:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

plt.bar(labels, data)
plt.xlabel('Categories')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.title('Chart Title')
plt.show()
```

> 5. Convert the chart to HTML using the mpld3 library:

```py
import mpld3

chart_html = mpld3.fig_to_html(plt.gcf())
```

> 6. Create a marker on the map and attach the chart HTML to it:

```py
marker = folium.Marker(location=[marker_latitude, marker_longitude])
marker.add_child(folium.Popup(chart_html))
marker.add_to(m)
```

Replace marker_latitude and marker_longitude with the coordinates of the marker's location.

> 7. Save the map as an HTML file:

```py
m.save('map_with_chart.html')
Now, if you open the map_with_chart.html file in a web browser, you should see the map with the chart attached to the marker.
```

Comment: Thanks you but this is not what I want. I need a floating chart instead of a chart pop up when clicking on a marker.